# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert the values using PDO statement using ajax. but everytime it throws mysql error. something is missing!

```
$st = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO payment_tbl (user_id, payment_mode, bank_name, cheque_no, pending_amt) 
       VALUES(  :user_id, :payment_mode, :bank_name, :cheque_no, :pending_amt )');


 $st->bindParam('user_id' , $user_id);
 $st->bindParam('payment_mode' , $pmode1);
 $st->bindParam('bank_name' , $bank_name1);
 $st->bindParam('cheque_no' , $cheque_no1);
 $st->bindParam('paid_amt' , $paid_amt1);

 $st->execute();
```

Comment: you forgot `:` in bindParam in all lines. And one typo in `$st->bindParam('paid_amt' , $paid_amt1);` it should be :- `$st->bindParam(':pending_amt' , $paid_amt1);`

Comment: shyamm  did you get the answer?

Comment: I found another solution without using bindParam() i.e.

Comment: $st = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO payment_tbl (user_id, payment_mode, bank_name, cheque_no, transaction_date, remark)
    VALUES( '$user_id' , '$pmode1' , '$bank_name1', '$cheque_no1', '$trans_date' , '$remark')");

Comment: It's not a solution but a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple issue of a typo. Should

```
    $st->bindParam('paid_amt' , $paid_amt1);
```

be

```
    $st->bindParam('pending_amt' , $pending_amt);
```

instead?

Comment: For the questions caused by a typo you have to vote to close them, not answer

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't... I don't have reputation to do so.  But I'm sure you knew that.

Comment: @chrisg  you pointed correct thing. so +1. but still answer is not complete. you can look to my answer